# How do I use imagemagick to join two images and resize them according to a given rule?

Tags: imagemagick

I have two images: `A.png` and `B.png`.

I want to put the B image on the top-left of A.png, and resize them to two new widths.

What command should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, you can do that in ImageMagick as follows:

A:

[image]

B:

[image]

```
convert \
\( B.png -resize 50x -set page "-%w-%h" \) \
\( A.png -resize 200x -set page +0+0 \) \
-layers merge +repage \
result.png
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: May I know what does `\ ` mean?

Comment: In ImageMagick unix syntax, the \ at the end of line, marks the end of line with a continuation to the next line. If you remove those and make the text one long string in one line, it will work fine. It is easier to read when the \ are there to wrap to the next line. The \ before ( and before ) are needed in Unix. In windows the parentheses do not need the \ as an escape. But the end of line \ are replaced by ^.